# How to get the word frequency of full-text search in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, full-text-search

I have several documents like this:

```
    text: "hello, I am your friend"
```

```
    text: "hello, hello"
```

```
    text: "everybody said: hello hello"
```

In full-text search, I want to count the number of times the search term appears,
For example, a search for "hello" will return 5 results.
I tried to use aggregate search and the result returned was the number of documents.

How to construct such a query?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [explain API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-explain.html) but you'd have to feed matching documents one by one. Look for the field with `"description":"freq, occurrences of term within document"`

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I will try it :)